# Error Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT {“code”:0,"messa…@

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I develop android application. With the help of the retrofit2.3.0, the application loads from the server xml and tries to process it, but for some reason an error occurs

```
  Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token 
  (position:TEXT {"code":0,"messa...@1:63340 in 
   okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader@534d7670) 
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:426)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.read(PullReader.java:105)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.next(PullReader.java:89)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeReader.readElement(NodeReader.java:111)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeReader.readRoot(NodeReader.java:85)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeBuilder.read(NodeBuilder.java:84)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeBuilder.read(NodeBuilder.java:71)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:562)
    at retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.convert(SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.java:36)
    ... 9 more
```

this xml in server

```
  <response>
   <code>0</code>
   <message>
     <item>
       <point_id>6320</point_id>
       <shop_id>4215</shop_id>
       <point_address>
       Russia, Moscow.
       </point_address>    
       </item>
      </message>
     </response>
```

please help me.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar error while parsing XML:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT ﻿@1:2 in java.io.StringReader@b7f960d)
```

As I found out, it was problem with encoding. File was encoded with UTF-8-BOM.
After converting the file first to UTF-8 and then parsing, problem was gone.